# siunitx - What is the best way to write "million"?

Tags: siunitx

Is this a good way to write "million"? How do you do it? Initially I used the scientific notation of the value but of course this got silly fast.

**What do you do in this case?**

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    amsmath
}
\usepackage{
    siunitx,
    eurosym
}

\DeclareSIUnit{\million}{\text{million}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\text{\euro}}


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item What I wrote before \SI{3.5e6}{\EUR}
    \item Now: \SI{3.5}{\million\EUR}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need to tell us the *context* in which this snippet will appear. If it's running text -- say, "Last year, the CEO was paid 3.5 million euros." -- I think you should write out the word "million" (and "euros" too, for that matter). If the snippet occurs within a table and you're dealing with some monetary amounts in the thousands, millions, and billions, using exponential notation is likely more suitable. And, for sure, do take into account conventions -- which may vary across currencies and regions -- as to whether the currency symbol should be placed *before* or *after* the amount.

Comment: The conventions are as displayed in the MWE. The context bit is a good point though. In this case it is running text. Yet the numbers also do appear in a tabular (in regards to annual reports) where .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal taste of an individual and the context under consideration.

Comment: @Masroor There is a `close`-button for that.

Comment: If I can write `kJ` for kilajoules, then perhaps you can write `M€` for million euros. But that's not very conventional `;-)`.

Comment: What makes matter worse is that the common abbreviation for million in English is 'm'.