# Sinunitx, fourier, euro, utf8 problem

Tags: symbols, siunitx, fourier

In this MWE, I can't have € in math mode since I've updated `siunitx` package.
Before it worked fine.

I found that take the `fourier` package off make it work again

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

    \RequirePackage{fourier}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}

    \setmainfont{Erewhon}[
        Extension=.otf,
        UprightFont=*-Regular,
        ItalicFont=*-Italic,
        BoldFont=*-Bold,
        BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
        SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
        BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
        SmallCapsFont=*-SmallCaps,
        SmallCapsFont=*-Regular,
        SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
        ]


\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    locale=FR,
    detect-all,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
    group-minimum-digits=4} 


\begin{document}
\SI{3}{€}       % works

$\SI{3}{€}$     % works only without fourier
\end{document}
```

Comment: You'd see the same with `$\mathrm{€}$`, so it's entirely unsurprising (I've tightened up on getting math mode 'right').

Comment: I'm desapointed, it worked on previous version ;-( I have plenty documents with € using SI in math mode...

Comment: Don't use `detect-all`, then: sorry but the old behaviour was wrong (as you should always be able to strip back from what `siunitx` does to a hand-written version).

Comment: Without `detect-all` no more € even in text mode. I maybe missunderstood some thing. By the way $\SI{3}{\text{€}}$ works fine. Is it possible to switch `mathrm{}` to `\text{}` ?

Comment: `unit-mode = text`

Comment: I add this line in the `sisetup`, it has no effect.

Comment: Thank you for this question(!) I worked hours on the problem the the EUR symbol was not displayed with several snippets on texexchange (like : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187031/siunitx-what-is-the-best-way-to-write-million) . But switching back to `unit-mode=text`made it for me. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some time ago I flipped the standard setting for units from text to math mode. You can reverse this by setting `unit-mode = text`, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{unit-mode = text} 
\begin{document}
\SI{3}{€}
$\SI{3}{€}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have forgotten to take off `detect-all`.